# проблема с word-spacing

Tags: html, css

делаю вот такой header
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

лого оформил, но правые слова(раздел меню) не могу расчленить по word-spacing,помогите пожалуйста как сделать так что бы все слова были красиво разрезаны между собой, потому-что word-spacing работает криво

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  width: 75%;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  height: 80px;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 29px;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 70px;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

.home {
  word-spacing: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo"><b>Black</b> + White</div>
    <div class="menu">
      <div class="home">home</div>
      <div class="home">our services</div>
      <div class="home">how we work</div>
      <div class="home">testimonials</div>
      <div class="home">work examples</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: что именно не так работает не так? Как должно было показываться?

Comment: показываться должно как на картинке,при моем выполнении кода одни слова слиты между собой,другие нормальные

Comment: word-spacing работает, у тебя нет отступов между элементами `.home` - задай их и не будет склеиваться

Comment: отступы между flex элементами можно задать, например, с помощью [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)

Comment: ну во1 это диватоз - делать меню на `div`. во2 вам нужно определиться с состоянием пунктов меню при наведении. `word-spacing` тут не при чем, нужны, так или иначе, отступы между пунктами меню. их можно реализовать по разному, в зависимости от пункта во1.

Comment: вопрос в этом и состоит,как их сделать? пытаюсь сделать через word-spacing,не получается.

Comment: @Vitaliy, `word-spacing` работает с текстом. У тебя элементы, внутри flex контейнера. для того, чтобы сработал `space-between` - пустое место должно быть в контейнере, а сейчас у тебя его ширина по контенту выбирается. задай для `menu` например `flex-grow: 1` - чтобы занять свободное место, и увидишь, что пробелы между пунктами есть

Comment: @Grundy очень сложно пошла информация. я просто сделал через space-between и поправил их марджинами

Answer (score 0):

Это не исчерпывающий список, выбирайте. Обратите внимание на состояние наведения, а так же, когда вы поставите в пункты меню ссылки, на область которая является ссылкой. Она может отличаться от визуального состояния и это будет напрягать пользователей.

```css
ul,
li {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.flex-gap {
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.padding li {
  padding: 10px;
}

.border li {
  border: 10px solid transparent;
}

.margin li {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>flex gap</h2>
<ul class="flex-gap">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
<h2>border</h2>
<ul class="border">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
<h2>padding</h2>
<ul class="padding">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
<h2>margin</h2>
<ul class="margin">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```